# problem to make a query REST put, a elasticsearch

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, curl, put

I want to send data in the format json a elasticsearch but I can not do it

I'm using elasticsearch version 7.0.1 and curl 7.64, I'm on windows 10

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "name": "John Doe"
}
'
```

i have this error messages :

> {
>       "error" : "Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported",   "status" : 406
>
> }
>
> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
>
> curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, you need to use double quotes everywhere, not single quotes:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"name\": \"John Doe\" }"
```